# Finding and plotting parabola in matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I have been trying to find a parabola in an image. For the starting purposes I took an image with a black parabola on a white background. Then I found the black pixels on the image using the find command by

```
[yi xi] = find(im<10); % im is the image with black parabola and white background
```

After that I randomly took 3 points from the collection and solved the equation for the parabola using the symbolic toolbox using

```
syms x y;
%solve them for the parabola equation
A  = [ x^2 x y 1 ;x0^2 x0 y0 1; x1^2 x1 y1 1; x2^2 x2 y2 1];
```

where

> %(x0,y0) = (104,137)
>
> %(x1,y1) = (244,161)
>
> %(x2,y2) = (300,229)

```
S = solve(det(A),y);
```

Then I get the coeffcients a,b,c as

> a = 0.0100
>
> b = -1.6800
>
> c = 254.1900

where a, b and c are

```
a*x^2 + b*x + c = y;
```

Since now I have got the eqn I plot the parabola by putting the coefficient values
and taking

```
 xx = 1:300;

 yy = a*xx.^2 + b*xx +c ;
```

then I plot the parabola on the image as

```
 plot(xx,yy,'-');
```

For the confirmation that I have taken correct points I also plot the selected points on the image and they lie exactly on the parabola in the image. So that is not the problem.

The problems are :

1. The parabola that I plot (blue) doesn't lie on the parabola of the image(black).
2. When I put the value of x co-ordinates in the above equation. The value of y is not the same as of the y co-ordinate.

   > for eg:  (104,137)
   >
   > 0.0100*104*104 -1.68*104 + 254.19 = 108.16 - 174.72 + 254.19 = 187.63
   >   whereas it should be **137**

My parabola is wrong. Any help will be appreciated. The images are [image: parabola from the equation(blue) plotted on the image(black)]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, especially without telling what you use to generate the parabola (ie how can we re-generate it) and how you construct the image (imshow, plot, ...)

Comment: I am asking why the blue parabola is not on the black one. The * points are the points that I have used to generate the coefficients (a,b,c). The black parabola is the original image. The blue parabola is what I have plotted with the first eqn given above. The y values are calculated by putting (a,b,c) and x values are taken from 1 to number of cols in image. so x = 1:300, y = a*x^2+b*x+c. plotting is plot(xx,yy,'-')

Comment: I think there is some problem with calculating the coefficients. Please update the question and include some code of that. (Ideally, provide the coordinates of the three points _and_ the code)

Comment: You might also show the values of coefficients you extracted and the original equation (with its own coefficients)

Comment: Ya show all the code including your plotting code. It could be a coordinate system difference or something like that.

Comment: You can find the parabola in a much easier way : use `polyfit`.

Comment: As @Andrey suggests, `[p,S,mu] = polyfit(x,y,n)` is a robust way to fit a parabola

Comment: Thanks @ Andrey , @Try Hard .  I am trying polyfit right now Will update you soon.

Comment: Hi @Andrey your suggestion is good.But polyfit works on least squares and as I have mentioned somewhere below that I am applying randomized hough transform, so I just don't want a 2nd degree polynomial which satisfies the least squares but I want that second degree polynomial on which most points lie. The hough accumulator helps me in finding that. Thanks for the polyfit hint. It will help me save lot of time in other modules. If there is any other option please add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must be rounding somewhere in your calculation of a, b, and c.

I had a go with the three points you mentioned using the function fit (with fit type poly2) and my a,b,c were 0.0053, -1.6802 and 254.1895 (or add more decimal places when using format long).

Similarly, when using same the code you give, the output of solve is:

```
S = (73*x^2)/13720 - (5763*x)/3430 + 87187/343
S2 = double(coeffs(S))

S2 =

  254.1895   -1.6802    0.0053
```

This gives me the same a, b, and c as with fit/poly2 (just from looking at it, the output of 73/13720 cannot be 0.01).  Also, if I plot this curve over the original points using the same code you give, it works fine. So the only remaining source of error that I can see is some sort of rounding in whatever code you use to extract values of a, b, and c from the output of solve.

Comment: You are right. I am rounding off to two decimal places using roundn(a,-2). I was rounding it as I was implementing randomized hough transform for parabola and there was problem in comparing double values of the coefficients for different parabolas. I am extremely sorry I missed the rounding part as I thought  it will be insignificant. Thanks a lot

Comment: @t0mkaka You might try normalizing the equation prior to solving it (removing the mean and dividing by the stdev of the data), that should make the solution more robust to truncation I would think.

Comment: @TryHArd Normalizing the equation is good. Thanks for the tip off.

Answer (score 0):

The following works. The habit of imshow to swap the intuitive meaning of ordinate and abscissa as used in plot can make overlays problematic at times. Your problem might stem from how you define your coordinate system *when plotting* with different function (imshow or related image display routines versus plot) in particular the position of the origin in the image. Here's my code:

```
% create image of parabola
k =[-0.3 10 10];
x = [1:0.1:50];
y = round(k(1)*x.^2 + k(2)*x + k(3));
crd = unique(round([x(:) y(:)]),'rows');
Nx = 100;
Ny = 100;
img = ones(Nx,Ny)*255;
iok = find((crd(:,1)>0) & (crd(:,1)<=Nx) & (crd(:,2)>0) & (crd(:,2)<=Ny));
indx = sub2ind([Nx Ny],crd(iok,1),crd(iok,2));
img(indx) = 0;
imshow(img)
```

Next we fit the parabola

```
% pick three points:
x0 = crd(1,1);
y0 = crd(1,2);
x1 = crd(80,1);
y1 = crd(80,2);
x2 = crd(160,1);
y2 = crd(160,2);
% plot these on the original image
hold on
plot(y0,x0,y1,x1,y2,x2,'Markersize',20,'Linestyle','none','Marker','x','Color','r')
```

Solved the equation precisely as you showed, then the result is

> S  = -1094/3627*x^2+12073/1209*x+37415/3627

Overlay the fitted equation

```
a= -1094/3627;
b = 12073/1209;
c = 37415/3627;
xx = 1:100;
yy = a*xx.^2 + b*xx +c ;
% then I plot the parabola on the image as
plot(yy,xx,'g--');
```

A not so pretty plot (green= fit, red crosses=picked points, blue=parabola plotted without swapping order of x and y):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But @nkjt answer solved my immediate problem. I have also thought about the co-ordinate system changes for the images in matlab and had done the required changes. Thanks again.